# Need facebook logout if user logout from my application

Tags: facebook, joomla

In my joomla application I am facing a problem . user can log in my application through facebook ,but I want whenever user log out from my application,  it must be log out from facebook account too.

Please give me your suggestion or any idea how can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Facebook Connect?

If so, just do the following in JavaScript:

```
FB.Connect.logout(); // old JS API
FB.logout(); // new JS API
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.logout

Comment: which JavaScript SDK are you using? im using the old JS API and FB.Connect.logout() works for me in ALL browsers.

Comment: We can use this link. http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=http://example.com   You can fix your return URL and site logout URL in next parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting to another page along with or immediately after the FB.logout call?

I have found that FF and Chrome will execute the FB.logout call quickly enough for this to work properly but that IE and mobile browsers (because of network speed in addition to differences in the JavaScript engine) will not complete the call successfully before the browser loads whatever page you're redirecting to.

So, the safest thing is to put any redirect into a callback function and pass that to FB.logout like this:

```
function mysignout(url)

{
    FB.logout(function()
    {
        top.location.href = 'url'
    });
}
```

I was originally putting FB.logout directly in the onclick event of an anchor link and while that worked in FF and Chrome it did not work in IE or in my Android browser. Doing the above made it work in all environments.

Surprisingly, it take 2+ seconds for FB.logout to completely successfully in most environments. There is obviously some kind of ajax call involved to revoke authentication on the server, not just destroying the local cookie.